# Retrieving a Variable output from IF or ELSE condition in KOTLIN

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to retrieve the output value from else condition in Kotlin.  I am not sure how to store the data outside If or Else condition. Any help is appreciated.

```
  else
        {
            var data=db.readData()

            for (i in 0..data.size - 1)
            {
                var data=db.readData()
                var output=data.get(i).name
                println("Result is $output")
            }

        }

//Need to Get Output here
var test=output??
```

Comment: Declare `output` before the if statement `var output=""` and inside else block change to `output=data.get(i).name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removed the var inside else condition then I am able to display the output outside else condition.

```
Code:
    var output:String="Hello" 
    else
            {
                var data=db.readData()

                for (i in 0..data.size - 1)
                {
                    var data=db.readData()
                    output=data.get(i).name
                    println("Result is $output")
                }

            }

    //Outside Else Condition
    println("Output Value is: $output")
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variable `output` outside `if-else`

Comment: I tried that option already something like var output:String="Test". If I retrieve the value then I am getting output "Result is Test" not the value from for loop.

Comment: That means either the "else" code is not executing or the for loop is not executing

Answer (score 0):

Declare `output` before `if-else` statement:

```
var output: String = ""
if(...){
    ...
}else{
    ...
    output = data.get(i).name          
}
```